# Hint for generic type seems wrong in the playground?

Tags: typescript, generics, contravariance

Consider the following code:

```
interface MyMouseEvent {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

interface MyKeyboardEvent {
  key: string;
}

interface MyEventObjects {
  click: MyMouseEvent;
  keypress: MyKeyboardEvent;
}

function handleEvent<K extends keyof MyEventObjects>(
  eventName: K,
  callback: (e: MyEventObjects[K]) => void
) {
  
}

handleEvent();
handleEvent('click', (e: MyMouseEvent) => {});
```

Error popup for the call with no args says callback is `(e: MyMouseEvent | MyKeyboardEvent) => void`. But by my understanding of covariance *if that is the correct type for `callback`, that second call should fail*. But it doesn't. And indeed, it seems like the popup is wrong:

```
function test(f: (e: MyMouseEvent | MyKeyboardEvent) => void): void {}
test('click', (e: MyMouseEvent) => {});
```

The call to `test` *does* fail, and fails with exactly the message I would expect. So my understanding is that the popup for `callback` in the no argument call to `handleEvent` is actually `(e: MyMouseEvent) => void | (e: MyKeyboardEvent) => void`. Is this correct?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=40&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE9UHsCuBnCAUQDcJxkBvAKGWQA8AuZEHAWwCNoBuG5dJlh25UAvlSqhIsRCgwBpCOnZY4UACYkyYSrwDWipnjBRQAcx5iJ4aPCRp0m8AHl2AKwgIweHbQQAbYARdJgxsfCJScB5afXQABygIPDwQ9AUlFXVHMAtxGBwQT2AsEGQACzgQNT8IrQAeOWQIOkgq71isGHtsl3dPPAA+AApeCEiwADk4VggmOQAaXgQ4Pz92RGDkIdnu8d6PLwBtOQBdAEpkAF4B5GIsYDUqC+paUXEKqprsobOeD+rauAhgByfyBXTA+ZbHahXAEbIXa6UES-PIFIolZCQIxDGBMbapMLw8bIAA+9nSylUGnGiJudweZyYDLUyKo2LAPx4HJBYKCkOhhLhgLAdORqKAA)